# How to get the value from the dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sumoselect.js

I have a dropdown menu which contains the checkboxes that can be multi selected using [SumoSelect](https://hemantnegi.github.io/jquery.sumoselect/).Here is the Markup for dropdown menu..

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="somename" id="uq" class="select">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
</select>
```

and here is the jquery function to get the dropdown click event ...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.select').SumoSelect({});
        var v = $("#uq").val();

    });
```

I am following this [link](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?iF5ue7jr) to get the multiselect checkbox option in dropdown menu but i am not getting how to get the value.

Please help me ..Thanks...

Update

```
$("#submit").click(function (evnt) {
    evnt.preventDefault();
    alert(v);
    console.log(v);
});
```

Update 2

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       $('.select').on('change', function (e) {
           console.log($(this).val()) // value
       }).SumoSelect({});

       $("#submit").click(function (evt) {
           evt.preventDefault();

           var v = $("#uq").val();
           alert(v)
```

Comment: This JS code doesn't listen for event at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind to the `change` event and get the value as such

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.select').on('change', function(e) {
        console.log($(this).val()) // value
    }).SumoSelect({})
});
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/rv5ps0r3/) - scroll to bottom for `.ready` code

Comment: Great! and if you wish to get the value in a `click` event or something, just call `$('.select').val()`

Comment: hey I need your help one more time ..I tried to implement the same in my application .I added `  $('.select').on('change', function (e) {
               console.log($(this).val()) // value
           }).SumoSelect({});` in document.ready and `  alert($('.select').val());` in button click event but i am not able to see the checkbox in dropdown menu ..Please help me ..Thanks

Comment: @RadheyPandey can you reproduce the error in a JSFiddle? Do tou get any errors in the console?

Comment: Please see update 2 in my post .I tried to implement like this way ..But I am not able to get dropdown menu click event ..and so on no value also

Comment: @RadheyPandey what element is `submit`? please provide the html as well

Comment: `submit` is submit button .HTML is `<input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" style="left: 1101px; z-index: 1; position: absolute; top: 148px; height: 31px; width: 88px;"/>`

Comment: @RadheyPandey I tried to reproduce for you and it works for me. Check out [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q54aLhq5/). Could it be something else? Do you get any JS errors in your console?

Comment: I am also doing the same.but i dont know why it is not happening .I am not able to get the dropdown menu with checkboxes means nothing is happening on dropdown HTML click event.Also i am not getting any kind of error in Console

Comment: make sure your click function is closed, in your edit you are missing a closing `});` could that be it? Open your developer console..do you see any errors.

Comment: yes its closed and i am not seeing any kind of error in console ..I dont know what is happening ?If you want i can give you the TeamViewer access of my system.Please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can read the value(s) as recently as the choices are made.
E.g.:

```js
$('#read-btn').click(function(){
  var v = $("#uq").val();
  alert(v)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" name="somename" id="uq" class="select">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
</select>
<button id="read-btn">read all choices</button>
```